# How to send h.264 video to browser using sockets

Tags: h.264, rtsp, rtp, mse

I'm trying to find a way to send streaming video (rtsp/rtp) from my camera to a browser.  I currently rely on ffmpeg, but I want a full javascript solution.  I'm able to decode the stream into NAL units. The next step appears to be to create the Initialization segment (ftyp and moov) and then the video segments.  That's where I'm stuck.  I can't seem to find any specifications that detail the content I need to send to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3 clearly documents it here https://www.w3.org/TR/mse-byte-stream-format-isobmff/

Also check out mux.js

Comment: Thank you.  I had read that document, but it appeared to be an overview.  I see now that it references ISO/IEC 14496-12 which is where the meat is.  Thanks again.